# How to allow catchError in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

So I fixed one of my organisation's needs by adding a `catchError` statement in one of their groovy files but in turn this creates a build error with a generic Jenkins test library `BasePipelineTest`:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin -   PipelineTest.testCall_AllFieldsAvailable:71 ? MissingMethod No signature
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin -   PipelineTest.testCall_FieldsNotAvailable:130 ? MissingMethod No signature
```

As part of the Jenkins standard `BasePipelineTest` class the solution for this is typically:

```
helper.registerAllowedMethod("cleanWs", []) {}
```

For a method like `cleanWs()`, or something similar depending on the method and its inputs. However this is for methods with input values, but `catchError` doesn't have input values, rather it's done like:

```
catchError {
    ...
}
```

So `helper.registerAllowedMethod("catchError", []) {}` does not work. Does anyone know how to make it work for something like `catchError`?

I have also attempted:

```
 helper.registerAllowedMethod("catchError", [com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.catchError]) {}
```

This creates a `MissingProperty` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the curly brackets themselves register as a class in groovy. I fixed it with:

`helper.registerAllowedMethod("catchError", [Closure.class]) {}`